# Location-tracking app suspends in background after few minutes

Tags: ios, background, xamarin.ios, xamarin, cllocationmanager

I try to create a location-tracking app. **App should work in background**. So, I switch on properties "Enable background modes", "location updates" and added parameter "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" to the source.

On ios7 app works fine, but on ios8 it suspends in background after few minutes (How app should work: I send a request every time when new location is received, and if I can see this request on the server it means that app is working).

I downloaded xamarin.mobile component with location functionality and used it instead of my class for geolocation. App also suspends in the background.

I created Objective-C app with the same functionality and tested it on the same device. Result - app works fine (as expected).

So, maybe app still needs some setting or I'm missing something?

```
public class LocationUpdatedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    CLLocation location;

    public LocationUpdatedEventArgs(CLLocation location)
    {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public CLLocation Location
    {
        get { return location; }
    }
}

protected CLLocationManager locMgr;
public event EventHandler<LocationUpdatedEventArgs> LocationUpdated = delegate { };
public GeoLocationService_iOS()
    {
        this.locMgr = new CLLocationManager();
        LocationUpdated += SaveLocation;

        locMgr.AuthorizationChanged += (object sender, CLAuthorizationChangedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            //CheckStatus();
        };

        if (locMgr.RespondsToSelector(new Selector("requestAlwaysAuthorization")))
        {
            locMgr.RequestAlwaysAuthorization();
        }

        locMgr.DistanceFilter = 1;
        locMgr.DesiredAccuracy = CLLocation.AccuracyBest;

        locMgr.LocationsUpdated += (object sender, CLLocationsUpdatedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            // fire our custom Location Updated event
            this.LocationUpdated(this, new LocationUpdatedEventArgs(e.Locations[e.Locations.Length - 1]));
        };

        locMgr.StartUpdatingLocation();
    }

    public void SaveLocation(object sender, LocationUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        SendLoc();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
locMgr.PausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false;
```

solved my problem.